# Slow SQL Query - Can't Find

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

OK, So my hosting company has suspended my account for the 4th damn time. This is annoying me because the code they say that is causing the problem:

```
# Mon Mar  5 11:00:00 2012
# Query_time: 4.028706  Lock_time: 0.000272 Rows_sent: 15  Rows_examined: 12188513 use futureg2_imbc; 

SELECT uploadsNew.id   ,
    uploadsNew.title   , uploadsNew.genre   , uploadsNew.content   ,
    uploadsNew.url   , uploadsNew.approved, (IF(v.views IS NOT NULL,
    v.views, 0) + IF(vc.old_views IS NOT NULL, vc.old_views, 0)) AS views,
    r.likes   , r.dislikes FROM uploadsNew   
  LEFT JOIN    
    (SELECT id   ,
      COUNT(*) AS views   
     FROM views   
    WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '1'  
    GROUP BY id   
    ) AS v   
  ON v.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT
      id   , SUM(views) AS old_views   
    FROM viewsCondensed   
    WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '1'   
    GROUP BY id   
    ) AS vc   
  ON vc.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT upload   , SUM(IF(rating = '1', 1, 0)) AS likes   , 
      SUM(IF(rating = '-1', 1, 0)) AS dislikes   ,
      IF(username = '', rating, 0) AS user_rated   
    FROM ratingNew   
    WHERE ratingNew.type = '0'   
    GROUP BY upload ) AS r   
  ON r.upload = uploadsNew.id   
  WHERE uploadsNew.type = '1'   AND uploadsNew.status ='0'   AND 
    uploadsNew.school = 'illinois-state-university'   
GROUP BY
  uploadsNew.id ORDER BY uploadsNew.approved DESC LIMIT 15
```

CAN'T EVEN BE ABLE TO RUN ON MY PAGE. Even after altering my code each and every time and looking at it at 100 times, this is still a problem and it is the exact same code, run multiple times per second, each time they suspend my account.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT uploadsNew.id
    , uploadsNew.title
    , uploadsNew.genre
    , uploadsNew.content
    , uploadsNew.url
    , uploadsNew.approved";
if($type < 3) $sql .= ", (IF(v.views IS NOT NULL, v.views, 0) + IF(vc.old_views IS NOT NULL, vc.old_views, 0)) AS views";
else $sql .= ", uploadsNew.member
    , uploadsNew.anonymous
    , r.ratedSong";
$sql .= ", r.likes
    , r.dislikes";
if($sort == "rated") $sql .= ", (r.likes - r.dislikes) AS rating";
if(isset($school)) $sql .= ", s.school_id";
$sql .= " FROM uploadsNew";
if(isset($school)) $sql .= " LEFT JOIN (SELECT url, id AS school_id FROM schools) AS s ON s.url = '". $school ."'";
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT id
                , COUNT(*) AS views
            FROM views
            WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '". $type ."'
            GROUP BY id
            ) AS v
            ON v.id = uploadsNew.id
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT id
                , SUM(views) AS old_views
            FROM viewsCondensed
            WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '". $type ."'
            GROUP BY id
            ) AS vc
            ON vc.id = uploadsNew.id
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT upload
                , SUM(IF(rating = '1', 1, 0)) AS likes
                , SUM(IF(rating = '-1', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
                , IF(username = '". $user['username'] ."', rating, 0) AS user_rated
            FROM ratingNew
            WHERE ratingNew.type = '0'
            GROUP BY upload
            ) AS r
            ON r.upload = uploadsNew.id
        WHERE uploadsNew.type = '". $type ."' AND uploadsNew.status = '0'";
if($genre) $sql .= " AND uploadsNew.genre = '". strtolower($genre) ."'";
if(isset($school)) $sql .= " AND uploadsNew.school = s.school_id";
else $sql .= $filter;
$sql .= " GROUP BY uploadsNew.id ORDER BY ". $s ." LIMIT ". ($page - 1) * $limit .", ". $limit;
```

If anyone can even figure out how the above code quoted can even run from that single query - feel free. Also if you can figure out HOW it is run multiple times per second (as if it was looped) I would love you even more.

Also, is the above approach efficient? I had another thread regarding this (well the database in general) and no one ever answered my question.

The support is giving me little help and keeps refering me to obvious things to look at. I feel the biggest thing is since the viewsCondensed table as roughly ~80k things.

Basically the viewsCondensed table is used to condense the daily views for everything (in the views table) to a fully daily sum (viewsCondensed).

Should I just change this into a weekly thing, or a monthly thing? I used to have all these just be a part inside the uploadsNew table though I felt this was somewhat inefficient and did not allow for actual data to be saved on a daily basis.

ANY AND ALL HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED!

---

Sorry, here is more data with EXPLAIN on the SELECT as well as on the various tables:

This is a NORMAL query that gets run on the page that the previous one "runs" on:

```
SELECT uploadsNew.id
  , uploadsNew.title
  , uploadsNew.genre
  , uploadsNew.content
  , uploadsNew.url
  , uploadsNew.approved, (IF(v.views IS NOT NULL, v.views, 0) + IF(vc.old_views IS NOT NULL, vc.old_views, 0)) AS views, r.likes
  , r.dislikes FROM uploadsNew
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT id
  , COUNT(*) AS views
  FROM views
  WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '1'
  GROUP BY id
  ) AS v
  ON v.id = uploadsNew.id
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id
  , SUM(views) AS old_views
  FROM viewsCondensed
  WHERE type = '0' AND subtype = '1'
  GROUP BY id
  ) AS vc
  ON vc.id = uploadsNew.id
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT upload
  , SUM(IF(rating = '1', 1, 0)) AS likes
  , SUM(IF(rating = '-1', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
  , IF(username = '', rating, 0) AS user_rated
  FROM ratingNew
  WHERE ratingNew.type = '0'
  GROUP BY upload
  ) AS r
  ON r.upload = uploadsNew.id
  WHERE uploadsNew.type = '1'
  AND uploadsNew.status = '0'
  GROUP BY uploadsNew.id ORDER BY uploadsNew.approved DESC LIMIT 15
```

**Explain on the above:**

```
1 PRIMARY uploadsNew     ref type,type_2               type_2 8 const,const 1965 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY <derived2>     ALL NULL                      NULL   NULL NULL     1335
1 PRIMARY <derived3>     ALL NULL                      NULL   NULL NULL     5429
1 PRIMARY <derived4>     ALL NULL                      NULL   NULL NULL      372
4 DERIVED ratingNew      ALL NULL                      NULL   NULL NULL     2111 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3 DERIVED viewsCondensed ref type,type_2,type_3,type_4 type_2 8            67475 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2 DERIVED views        index type                      id_2   12   NULL     4351 Using where; Using index
```

**Explain on the initial "problem" query:**

> 1 PRIMARY uploadsNew  ref type,type_2 type_2  8   const,const 1896    Using
>   where; Using temporary; Using filesort
>   1 PRIMARY   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    479 
>   1 PRIMARY   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6015
>   1 PRIMARY   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    384 
>   4 DERIVED ratingNew   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2171    Using where; Using
>   temporary; Using filesort
>   3 DERIVED viewsCondensed  ref type,type_2,type_3,type_4   type_3  4       53779   Using
>   where; Using temporary; Using filesort
>   2 DERIVED views   ref type    type    4       688 Using where; Using temporary;
>   Using filesort

**views table:**

> CREATE TABLE `views` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `type`
>   int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `subtype` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `date` datetime NOT NULL, `ip` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `user`
>   varchar(20) NOT NULL, KEY `id` (`id`,`type`), KEY `id_2`
>   (`id`,`type`,`subtype`), KEY `id_3` (`id`,`type`,`date`), KEY `type`
>   (`type`,`ip`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

**viewsCondensed table:**

> CREATE TABLE `viewsCondensed` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `subtype` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '0', `date` date NOT NULL, `views` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', KEY
>   `id` (`id`,`type`), KEY `id_2` (`id`,`type`,`subtype`), KEY `id_3`
>   (`id`,`type`,`date`), KEY `type` (`type`,`views`), KEY `type_2`
>   (`type`,`subtype`,`views`), KEY `type_3` (`type`,`date`,`views`), KEY
>   `type_4` (`type`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

**uploadsNew table:**

> CREATE TABLE `uploadsNew` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `member` varchar(30) NOT NULL, `ip` int(20) NOT NULL, `gallery`
>   varchar(30) NOT NULL, `type` int(1) NOT NULL, `genre` varchar(30) NOT
>   NULL, `anonymous` int(1) NOT NULL, `school` int(6) NOT NULL, `added`
>   datetime NOT NULL, `approved` datetime NOT NULL, `title` varchar(255)
>   NOT NULL, `content` varchar(2500) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(300) NOT
>   NULL, `address` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `tags` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>   `rating` int(1) NOT NULL, `status` int(1) NOT NULL, `source`
>   varchar(600) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `id`
>   (`id`,`member`,`status`), KEY `type`
>   (`type`,`genre`,`approved`,`rating`,`status`), KEY `type_2`
>   (`type`,`status`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6004 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1

**ratingNew table:**

> CREATE TABLE `ratingNew` ( `upload` int(10) NOT NULL, `type` int(1)
>   NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `ip` int(16)
>   NOT NULL, `rating` int(1) NOT NULL, `date` datetime NOT NULL, KEY
>   `upload` (`upload`,`type`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

---

More Edits (tried new query and explain):

**new query**

```
SELECT 
    uploadsNew.id,     uploadsNew.title, 
    uploadsNew.genre,  uploadsNew.content,
    uploadsNew.url,    uploadsNew.approved, 
    COALESCE(v.views, 0) + COALESCE(vc.old_views, 0) AS views,
    r.likes,           r.dislikes 
FROM  ( SELECT *
        FROM uploadsNew
        WHERE type = 1  
          AND status = 0  
        ORDER BY approved DESC 
        LIMIT 15
      ) AS uploadsNew  
  LEFT JOIN    
      ( SELECT  id,  COUNT(*) AS views   
        FROM views   
        WHERE type = 0 AND subtype = 1  
        GROUP BY id   
      ) AS v   ON v.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
      ( SELECT  id,  SUM(views) AS old_views   
        FROM viewsCondensed   
        WHERE type = 0 AND subtype = 1   
        GROUP BY id   
      ) AS vc  ON vc.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
      ( SELECT  upload, 
                SUM(rating = 1 ) AS likes, 
                SUM(rating = -1) AS dislikes,
                IF(username = '', rating, 0) AS user_rated   
        FROM ratingNew   
        WHERE type = 0   
        GROUP BY upload 
      ) AS r   ON r.upload = uploadsNew.id   
ORDER BY uploadsNew.approved DESC
```

The explain

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    15  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    479 
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6015    
1   PRIMARY <derived5>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    384 
5   DERIVED ratingNew   index   NULL    upload_3    34  NULL    2171    Using where; Using index
4   DERIVED viewsCondensed  ref type,type_2,type_3,type_4   type_3  4       53779   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED views   ref type    type    4       688 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED uploadsNew  range   type,type_2,type_3,type_4   type_4  4   NULL    5970    Using where
```

Comment: please take a deep breath and ask again.

Comment: Well, I'm sure some database guru can give you a more comprehensive answer, but I can say that having the SELECT statements for the JOINS is where this is slowing down. Each SELECT query gets run many many many times as the database engine tries to figure out how all this data relates to each other. Are you using MySQL 5+? If so, you should investigate VIEWS and STORED PROCEDURES where the database engine can figure what is going to happen with your query, and pre-process a lot of the nitty-gritty down low stuff.

Comment: You have not included the most important part of the code, which is the loop in which you're running the query. The query stats at the top suggest it had to examine over 12 million rows.  You should be running the query manually, and using EXPLAIN, to figure it out.  Even though you've written a lot, it's not the right information for anybody here to help you.

Comment: just like @dagon suggested, please take a deep breath and ask again

Comment: Does the query returns different result if you remove the `GROUP BY uploadsNew.id` ?

Comment: Are you sure its not run because multiple 'clients' are running the same code? Check orig. IP in your logs files. Maybe run a SQL EXPLAIN on the code and see what it brings you.

Comment: Like i said in my solution, sub selects are evil, why do you need to sub select? If you can find a way to not subselect, maybe by create views that you left join on, you could definitely save yourself trouble.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin:  Joining subselects (where grouping happens) is sometimes the only (or the best) way to get the results one wants.

Comment: To answer everyone's questions. I used subselects because a 'guru' on another form told me to do so. If there is a better way to to do the above I would gladly implement it. I also added a lot more information to the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `uploadsNew`? Is it the `id`? If yes, remove the `GROUP BY uploadsNew.id`. It should give identical results.
2. What indices do you have on the tables? If you haven't, add:

   - an index on `(type, subtype, id)` in table `views`
   - an index on `(type, subtype, id, views)` in table `viewsCondensed`.
   - an index on  `(type, upload, rating)` in table `ratingNew`.
   - an index on `(type, status, school, approved)` in table `uploadsNew`.
3. Then, (don't run the query yet), but use the EXPLAIN statement to get the query plan and post it here. It would also be good if you added the tables' definitions (so we know the datatypes and the indices you have).
4. Several of your tables do not have a `PRIMARY KEY`. This is not good but it's not the reason for the slowness of those 2 queries, so lets forget it for the moment (but you should take care of that later).
5. You have several redundant indices but that isn't either the reason for slow performance of the above queries, so lets skip that, too (but you should take care of that some time later, too).
6. Add the indices I've put in comment 2 above. The only one that might not be the best is the `(type, upload, rating)` in table `ratingNew`. It might have to be: `(type, upload, username, rating)` instead but if that table has not many rows it won't be a problem now.
7. Your code produces several variations of the query. So, you many also have to add this index, too: `(type, status, approved)` in table `uploadsNew`.

Then, try first the EXPLAIN on this variation and then run it:

```
SELECT 
    uploadsNew.id,     uploadsNew.title, 
    uploadsNew.genre,  uploadsNew.content,
    uploadsNew.url,    uploadsNew.approved, 
    COALESCE(v.views, 0) + COALESCE(vc.old_views, 0) AS views,
    r.likes,           r.dislikes 
FROM  ( SELECT *
        FROM uploadsNew
        WHERE type = 1  
          AND status = 0  
          AND school = 'illinois-state-university'   
        ORDER BY approved DESC 
        LIMIT 15
      ) AS uploadsNew  
  LEFT JOIN    
      ( SELECT  id,  COUNT(*) AS views   
        FROM views   
        WHERE type = 0 AND subtype = 1  
        GROUP BY id   
      ) AS v   ON v.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
      ( SELECT  id,  SUM(views) AS old_views   
        FROM viewsCondensed   
        WHERE type = 0 AND subtype = 1   
        GROUP BY id   
      ) AS vc  ON vc.id = uploadsNew.id   
  LEFT JOIN   
      ( SELECT  upload, 
                SUM(rating = 1 ) AS likes, 
                SUM(rating = -1) AS dislikes,
                IF(username = '', rating, 0) AS user_rated   
        FROM ratingNew   
        WHERE type = 0   
        GROUP BY upload 
      ) AS r   ON r.upload = uploadsNew.id   
ORDER BY uploadsNew.approved DESC
```

Comment: I just added all that information to the above problem, thanks.

Comment: I added your new query and EXPLAIN above as well as tried the indices you mentioned.

Comment: This one only took Query took 0.1760 sec

Answer (score 0):

You should never use sub selects, instead reformat it to use it just like a standard left join.

I have difficulty parsing your code like this so if you could instead paste us the result of the SQL STRING build, we'd be able to then reformat it as much as possible.

Comment: Its always nice to get confronted on that, sadly i had a conference with Dave Stokes, lead manager at MySQL that told me no later than 3 days ago that subqueries in MySQL should be avoided at all costs because it is know to be extremely slow. I see... 3 sub queries in there used as data sources... i rest my case...

Comment: I agree about correlated subqueries. But derived subqueries sometimes cannot be avoided (like this example where the OP wants to group by in several tables). How would that be rewritten without subqueries?

Comment: Use Views, views will be cached and optimized by default and you can left join on them easily....